# SignIn fails in Visual studio 2017 with reason : Winlnet cannot redirect

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Installed VS 2017 and trying to sign-in but getting the following error:
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a support site for Visual Studio installation problems.

Comment: Please redirect me to the right forum to get it resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following trick worked for me..
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/56104/the-browser-based-authentication-dialog-failed-to-1.html

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open the Visual Studio Installer.(https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/enterprise/)
3. Click on the report a problem link at the top.
4. On the left hand side, there should be a person icon to sign in. Sign in.
5. Close that, and open Visual Studio. You should now be signed in.
6. Then go to File -> Account Settings. You should see a license, or click check for an updated license. (I didn't need to do this step. Things started working before this point for me.)